# PostgreSQL cannot call json_object_keys on a scalar

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table with a JSON column, and I'm trying to get a list of all the distinct keys in that column. I created a query to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT json_object_keys(j) FROM t;
```

Where `t` is the table and `j` is the JSON column. This worked on a small set of data correctly, it would list all the keys that exist in `j`, without repeating them. However, after adding a lot more data, it doesn't work anymore, giving the error:

```
ERROR:  cannot call json_object_keys on a scalar
```

I'm not sure exactly why this is happening. By just limiting the query to certain rows one at a time, I found one that causes the error. In that row, `j` is `null`. However, calling `SELECT json_object_keys(null);` does not cause this error, while calling `SELECT json_object_keys(j) FROM t WHERE id=12;` does, and `j` in this row is just `null`. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

So I guess my question is what could be causing this, and how can I either work around it or prevent it from happening?

Running PostgreSQL 9.3.9

Edit: Ok, I may have posted this a little preemptively. I figured out that `j` in the problematic row isn't `null`, it's `'null'::json`, which wasn't clear from just selecting the row. This *does* cause the scalar error, so now I just have to figure out a way to select the rows where `j` isn't `'null'::json`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tried this query, to filter out the `'null'::json` values with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT json_object_keys(j) from t WHERE j <> 'null'::json;
```

However, apparently there is no json <> json operator, so I had to cast it to text and compare.

```
SELECT DISTINCT json_object_keys(j) from t WHERE j::TEXT <> 'null';
```

This works! I'm not a Postgres expert though, so this may not be the most effecient way of doing this check.

Comment: Also, for anyone using SQLAlchemy, setting `none_as_null=True` on JSON columns completely eliminates this problem...

Comment: Use `json_typeof(j)='array'`.

Comment: Thanks Peter. `json_typeof()` is a game-changer for me! Once I know the type of the value, I can do the correct extraction and operation on it as needed. `select json_typeof('{"a":[1,2,3], "c":"some text", "d":true, "e":1000, "f": {"q": 124}}'::json#>'{a}')`